# Oversight or the oversight

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

Totally confused on the need for an article in front of "oversight". Google gives examples of all the different variations. Would appreciate help choosing the right one from the following.

> A. Operated at a senior level to provide oversight of key aspects of
>   project and programme delivery.
>
> B. Operated at a senior level to provide **the** oversight of key aspects
>   of project and programme delivery.
>
> C. Operated at a senior level to provide **an** oversight of key aspects
>   of project and programme delivery.

Comment: There's no right way. What makes you think that one is correct over the others? Questions about indefinite versus definite articles get asked all the time here. What specific meaning are you intending to get across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking about *oversight* generally so no article or the indefinite article can be used.

> **The** oversight

would refer to  oversight of a specific job.

Comment: **"oversight of key aspects of project and programme delivery"** hmm, sounds pretty specific and NOT general to me. It's possible to use both indefinite, definite, or no articles in this instance. An example of when "the" would not be recommended: simply **"operated at a senior level to provide oversight to employees"**

Answer (score -1):

*oversight* is not an adjective. I am assuming you mean this:

> **oversight** (noun) the action of overseeing something.

I would go with B or C, because in these examples you would be referring to *the action*:

- C if this is the first time you are referring the oversight in the text.
- Otherwise, go with B.

However, your sentence also depends on what is "operated a senior level". If it is something which results in something equivalent to the action of overseeing, then I would go with:

> Operated at a senior level **so as** to provide an oversight of key aspects of project and programme delivery.